# visual basic error BC30456 'Form1' is not a member of 'WindowsApplication1'

Tags: vb.net

Hello I am trying to do an exercise and keep getting this error when compiling.

> Visual Basic error BC30456 'Form1' is not a member of 'WindowsApplication1'

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Below is my code:

```vb
Public Class frmCentsConverter
    Private Sub txtAmount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtAmount.TextChanged
        If IsNumeric(txtAmount.Text) Then
            Dim NumberofCents As Integer

            NumberofCents = CInt(txtAmount.Text)
            lblDollars.Text = CStr(NumberofCents \ 100)
            lblCents.Text = CStr(NumberofCents Mod 100)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblTitle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblTitle.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the instantiation of your class; you've instantiated as `Form1`, when it should be`frmCentsConverter`; i.e. `Dim frmConvert As New frmCentsConverter`, instead of `Dim frmConvert As New Form1`. It could also be that you've renamed the start-up form of the app and this hasn't cascade through to the Application setting.

Comment: Lets put it this way, your class is not even a form, because this `Public Class frmCentsConverter` doesn't have this `inherits Form`

Answer (score 9):

If you have renamed the startup form1 it is likely you also have to change the Startup form setting. You can find this setting to open 'My Project' in the 'Solution Explorer'. Select the Application section, change the 'startup form' as appropriate.

Hope this will help, Harrie

Answer (score 6):

**To set the startup form in Windows Forms**

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and choose Properties.
2. The Project property page opens with the Application properties displayed.
3. Choose the form you want as the startup form from the Startup Object drop-down list.

I got this information from this website:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a2whfskf(v=vs.100).aspx

I can confirm this works on Visual Studio 2015 as well.

Answer (score 4):

Under the tab, **Application.Designer.vb**

You'll see the following the code:

Me.MainForm = Global.WindowsApplication1.**Form1**

Change **Form1** to your **NEW form name**.

**Example:** Changed Form 1 "Hello World" to frmHello

**Original:**
Me.MainForm = Global.WindowsApplication1.Form1

**Change to:**
Me.MainForm = Global.WindowsApplication1.frmHello

Answer (score 1):

I know how to fix it.

If you get this problem, open the error message by clicking the error line until Application.Designer.vb shows up & then find the "Form1" name in that place.

Sample in Application.Designer.vb tab:

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
        Me.MainForm = Global.aplikasi_set_diskumau.Form1
    End Sub
```

I found the "Form1" name in that part of code, just replace that "Form1" with the name of your form.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bug after form renaming.

Try to change file `Application.myapp` under Project Folded

```
<MainForm>Form1</MainForm>
```

p.s. `Application.Designer.vb` is created dynamically, so changes there would be overwritten after the next clean build.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it.

1. Right click on the Name of your project and then click properties.
2. Locate the Target framework under the Applications tab.
3. Change it to ".NET Framework 4.5" (mine was on 4.5.2).
4. Click/accept/whatever it is to confirm your selection from the popup box.
5. Build/Rebuild solution.
   This worked for me in VB.net 2015.
   Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by changing to .NET Framework 3.5, clean and rebuild, then change back to 4.8. For some reason it seems 4.8 is not updating Application.Designer.vb properly. By the way, updating that file manually does not work, it will be overwritten in the next build.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i sitched in Visual Studio 2022 to a newer windows version that 7 and it showed me the error

> error BC30456 "Forms" is not Member of "Windows".

```
 Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
```

changing it to

```
DialogResult.No
```

resolved the isssue